# Explain why D3 cannot be a subgroup of D8

Tags: group-theory

To be a subgroup, a subset of a group must satisfy the group axiom but in this case, I do not see how the group axiom plays a part.

Could someone explain to me why the above question is true?

Comment: What is your definition of $D_3$ and $D_8$, explicitly?

Comment: Dihedral group of degree 3 and degree 8

Comment: Right, I know that - I mean, there are multiple possible definitions of "dihedral group" (all ultimately equivalent, of course). Are you thinking of them in terms of rotations, group presentations, etc.?

Answer (score 5):

The explanation is immediate from Lagrange's theorem. If you haven't seen that yet, are you sure that $D_3 \subset D_8$?

Comment: I am not sure, that's why I was hoping for clarifications.

Comment: To help out a little bit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29  Basically the issue is that $16/6$ is not an integer.  The left cosets of the subgroup have to "partition" the space evenly.

Comment: Ok, well, $D_3$ contains an element of order $3$. Does $D_8$? If you're not sure try writing out the group structure or playing with the symmetries of an octagon.

Answer (score 3):

By Lagrange's theorem we know that order of subgroup must divides order of group but here **D_3** has order 6 while **D_8** has order 16 and clearly 6 does not divides 16. so **D_3** cant be subgroup of **D_8**

Answer (score 1):

First, a group is a set together with a binary operation that satisfy some given conditions. On the other hand, $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ if $H$ is a subset of $G$ and satisfy all the properties of a group, under the same binary operation as $G$.

$D_3:=\langle x,y \mid x^3=y^2=1, xy=yx^{-1} \rangle = \{1,x,x^2,y,xy,x^2y\}$ while 
$D_8:=\langle x,y \mid x^8=y^2=1, xy=yx^{-1} \rangle = \{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6,x^7,y,xy,x^2y,x^3y,x^4y,x^5y,x^6y,x^7y\}.$

**$D_3$ is not a subgroup of $D_8$ because $D_3$ is not a subset of $D_8$ under the same binary operation.**

For instance $x^2$ has order $3$ in $D_3$ while $x^2$ has order $4$ in $D_8$. The reason why $x^2$ does not have the same order in both $D_3$ and $D_8$ is that the binary relation in both $D_3$ and $D_8$ are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, a group is a set together with a binary operation that satisfy some given conditions. On the other hand, $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ if $H$ is a subset of $G$ and satisfy all the properties of a group, under the same binary operation as $G$.

$D_3:=\langle x,y \mid x^3=y^2=1, xy=yx^{-1} \rangle = \{1,x,x^2,y,xy,x^2y\}$ while 
$D_8:=\langle x,y \mid x^8=y^2=1, xy=yx^{-1} \rangle = \{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6,x^7,y,xy,x^2y,x^3y,x^4y,x^5y,x^6y,x^7y\}.$

For instance $x^2$ has order $3$ in $D_3$ while same $x^2$ has order $4$ in $D_8$. The reason why $x^2$ does not have the same order in both $D_3$ and $D_8$ is that the binary relation in both $D_3$ and $D_8$ are not the same. **This is a first reason why $D_3$ is not a subgroup of $D_8$.** In other words, $D_3$ is not a subgroup of $D_8$ because $D_3$ is not a subset of $D_8$ under the same binary operation.